# Puppy growling - when should I be concerned?

Tags: dogs, aggression

Yesterday I adopted a puppy, and today was her first walk. She was quite scared at the beginning, but after a couple of minutes of walking, she felt comfortable. On my way back, we met another puppy (a male bulldog), and she was playing with him and with humans, but from nowhere, she started to growl and try to bit him - I'm not sure if she was playing with him or if she was being possessed. She didn't try to bite the humans'. How can I identify if she was aggressive? I have another dog (she doesn't have any contact with him), and in fact, she spent her first four months living with other adult dogs that are not aggressive at all. Also, we know that her mother was not aggressive.

Comment: Hi Amanda. Please be aware that "growling" is not always a sign of aggression. Just like dogs can bark from joy of seeing a family member again or to ward off an intruder, they can growl playfully or aggressively. As a dog owner, it's a great idea to watch some Youtube videos that demonstrate and explain the difference between joyful and aggressive vocalization. I also think that you could introduce both your dogs to each other and become one big family.